# How to say aloud fractions without the -ono suffix?

Tags: phrase-requests, numbers

I know that you can pronounce a fraction using the -ono suffix. However, in some situations it can be hard to parse; for example 2/10 is pronounced *du dekonoj* but can be mistaken for *dudekonoj*, that is 1/20. Is there another way to say fractions aloud?

Answer (score 2):

- 12 / 10 = **dekdu dekonoj** = **12 dividite de 10** *(3 syllables more)*
- 10 / 20 = **dek dudekonoj** = **10 dividite de 20**

Difference only audible by the pause for `onoj`. However pauses are a bit more used in E-o as in English - I think.

It would have been nice to have a shorter expression for `dividite de` (`per/super`?) but that is as it is.

For clearness by audio channel with noice (radio, phone), one can use the following trick:

- 12 / 10 = **dekdu da dekonoj**
- 10 / 20 = **dek da dudekonoj**

Comment: If I need to speak out polynomials or formulas with a division in _la espa_, I use _super_. So (x^2 + y^2) / (x-y) is spoken as "en krampoj ikso en kubo plus ipso en kubo fino de krampo super en krampoj ikso minus ipso fino de krampo"

Comment: @JuhaMetsäkallas `5 super 2`= `5 over 2`= 5! 4! 3! 2! 1! / 2! 1! 3! 2! 1!. Eble iuj mallongigas "dividite de" per "per" - tamen mi ne havas spertojn kun matematikistojn esperantajn.

Comment: Mi scias, ke oni minimume en la angla kaj en la sveda uzas `over` resp. `över` ĉi tiel kun du sencoj: `5 over 2 = 5/2 or 5 over 2 = 5! / ((5-2)! 2!)`. Eble oni faras ĉi tiel ankaŭ en la espa.